# How do I verify a payment transaction in a decentralized backend application?

Tags: web3.js

How can I verify a transaction performed in the chain on an independent service?
and how do I prevent it from being used again after using signature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are performing the transaction on your own platform. In such case you can get the transaction ID to ensure that the transaction is completed. You can store the transaction ID to ensure that it is not used again

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8NLKmb6.png I'm using a solution like the one in the image, but it doesn't work very stable because I'm using RPC.